# How to configure a cookie in the program.cs in ASP .NETCore 6 API and for Authentication

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

When login user, a cookie is created and sent to the browser.

In client browser, in the Inspect section, in the `Network` tab, there is cookie both in the `Headers` tab, in the  `ResponseHeaders` section marked with the `Set-Cookie` key, and in the `Cookies` tab.

But the cookie is not set in the `application` tab and in the storage section, and as a result, the `cookie` is not stored in the browser.

at frontend(React.js), can not read `Set-Cookie` in JavaScript.

I wanted to know if it is possible to send a cookie to the browser with another header or custom header?

Because I receive all `ResponseHeaders` except `Set-Cookie`.

Or can a cookie be set to be saved as soon as it reaches the browser?

I use Identity for login user.

my Program.cs:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);


builder.Services.AddControllers();

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();



builder.Services.Configure<CookieTempDataProviderOptions>(options => { options.Cookie.IsEssential = true; });

builder.Services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
{
    options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
    
    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;

});


builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, x =>
    {
    
        x.Cookie.Name = "mycookie";
       
        x.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;

    });




builder.Services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", build =>
    build.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().WithExposedHeaders("*")));




var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseSwagger();
   
}
app.UseCors("MyPolicy");

app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseCookiePolicy(
    new CookiePolicyOptions
    {
        Secure = CookieSecurePolicy.Always
    });

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

my login method:

```
 public void Signin(UserViewModel user)
        {
            
            var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim("AccountId", user.Id.ToString()),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Name),
           
            };

            var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

            var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(1)
            };

            _contextAccessor.HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity),
                authProperties);
            
        }
```

Thanks for those help me!

Answer (score -1):

[Please Check this Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Hope this helps.

Comment: this is a pretty useless answer. it could have been a comment and doesn't actually answer the question